# Python modules not found when using relative path names

Tags: python, python-module

I am running a script which uses the TQDM package. I ran the code in command prompt using the full path, which worked fine, but when I ran the same program using the relative path, it could not find the TQDM package. I wil paste the stack trace below, let me know if there is any more information I should give.

```
C:\Users\cmoss\OneDrive\Desktop\Tools>python -u "c:\Users\cmoss\OneDrive\Desktop\Tools\Python Scripts\multipleSCP.py"

Enter the STARTING DIRECTORY of the files you want to send (no quotes):


Enter where you want the file to be received (no quotes):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\cmoss\OneDrive\Desktop\Tools\Python Scripts\multipleSCP.py", line 37, in <module>
    receivingPath = input("\nEnter where you want the file to be received (no quotes):\n")        
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        
KeyboardInterrupt
^C

C:\Users\cmoss\OneDrive\Desktop\Tools>python3 -u "Python Scripts\multipleSCP.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cmoss\OneDrive\Desktop\Tools\Python Scripts\multipleSCP.py", line 5, in <module>
    from tqdm import tqdm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

Research has found me with no answers for my problem, I am unfamiliar with how to use environmental variables to my advantage so I am not sure what else I can do. This same issue is happening with other packages, not just TQDM. TQDM was installed with pip, so I would imagine that it would work with every python instance, it is not like I am using a package I created and have some random place in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple versions of python installed?
Once you call "python" in command promt and once you call "python3"

Comment: I was able to match the versions but the issue remains. I guess the path to python3 does not include the modules I have installed previously. I am fine with just using the python command rather than python3 from now on.

Comment: I dont think it has anything to do with relativePath vs fullPath.. never had this myself.
I suspect that its about dependencies and how you installed tdqm (pip or conda or something else). You can check all your dependencies and put the dependencies in a text file by "pip freeze  > requirements.txt" (should be available with "conda freeze" as well I think), and install it with something like "pip install -r requirements.txt".
Make sure that both python and python3 have the same dependencies and the same python-version